# Unable to retrieve all the key for a Map(HashMap)?

Tags: java, generic-collections

I am working on a client-server application in which server sends the indication and client receives those indication.The Map is declared as

```
private static Map<key,value> obj=new HashMap<key,value>();
```

The Map is getting the values through `synchronised(obj)` in constructor of the value Class

```
obj.put(this,this);
```

I am trying to retrieve the all the keys for this Map. I used  `Set<key> t=Map.KeySet();` but this throws a compile error saying can not found symbol :KeySet() in interface `java.util.Map.` Note:key is interface and value is the class in which Map is Declared.

Comment: `.put(this, this)?` What kind of `Map` is that? Can you show the code?

Comment: Is that you have tried `Map.keySet?` or `obj.keySet?`

Comment: @VinayVeluri I used Map.KeySet();

Comment: show your code that you tried

Comment: there is no static `KeySet()` method in `Map` interface. Did you mean `Map m = new HashMap(); Set set = m.keySet();`?

Comment: @Nilamber it's `.keySet()` (`k`, not `K`)

Comment: KeySet and keySet are different, Java is case-sensitive. There's no such method as KeySet. Also, why are you assigning the key and value to the same object? Why not just use a Set? Also, are 'key' and 'value' generics labels, and are they both assignable to 'this'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Map API once. Map is interface and you are trying to use the keySet() like you call a static method.

You should call the methods on the object created.

you should use `obj.keySet()`

[Map Api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

As you have written

```
private static Map<key,value> obj=new HashMap<key,value>();
```

You should write

```
Set<key> t=obj.keySet();
```

instead of `Set<key> t=Map.KeySet();`

Answer (score 0):

There is no KeySet method on Map, keySet is the correct method for getting the keys